# The h2 port 9001 doesn't close after completing the stop goal at the post-integration-test phase

Tags: java, maven, testing

> Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9001; nested exception is:
> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:243)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:412)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:234)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:220)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.(RegistryImpl.java:180)
> at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.SingleEntryRegistry.(SingleEntryRegistry.java:49)
> at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:836)
> at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:479)

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>

                        <configuration>
                            <profiles>test</profiles>
                            <wait>1000</wait>
                            <jvmArguments>
                                -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true
                            </jvmArguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <id>start</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wait>1000</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>180</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

H2 setting at the application.properties

```
jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE
```

netstat -noa | findstr :9001
TCP    0.0.0.0:9001           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8092
TCP    127.0.0.1:59868        127.0.0.1:9001         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    [::]:9001              [::]:0                 LISTENING       8092

When I used the h2 at the post-integration-test phase, unfortunately, h2 port 9001 doesn't close after doing the stop gaol by maven. Please help me to solve this problem that causes the start phase at the pre-start-integration test to face the following problem by executing again the maven verify command again